# what is max database size limit while using AMR tool?

Tags: sql-server-2014, in-memory-database

what is the max size of database used for AMR tool that we used to identify table/procedure that we can move in In-Memory OLTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google give this:

```
The recommended maximum size for memory-optimized tables is 256GB
```

Comment: Is this from an authoritative source? Can you include a link to the source?